# Cypher WHERE NOT EXISTS with named variable

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In a Neo4J database, I need to find a (complex) pattern with 3 named node (let's say a, b, c) and some other non-named nodes, but only if there is no node (say "x") that connects to a, b, and c.

I'd like to write something like :

```
MATCH (a:A)-<something>-(b:B)-<something>-(c:C)
WHERE NOT EXISTS ((a)--(x:X)--(b), (x)--(c) )
RETURN a, b, c
```

But I get "Variable `x` not defined". It would be easy if x was only forbidden if connected to (a) and (b). And `NOT EXISTS (a)--(:X)--(b) AND NOT EXISTS (a)--(:X)--(c)` is too strong.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try `MATCH`ing `x:X` and using it the `WHERE`:

```
MATCH (x:X), (a:A)-<something>-(b:B)-<something>-(c:C)
WHERE NOT EXISTS ((a)--(x)--(b), (x)--(c) )
RETURN a, b, c
```

Comment: Thanks, so simple! Is sounds that I need to split my "NOT EXISTS" parts in two:  
  
`MATCH 
  (x:X), 
  (a:A)-<something>-(b:B)-<something>-(c:C)
WHERE 
   NOT EXISTS ((a)--(x)--(b)) 
   AND NOT EXISTS((x)--(c) )
RETURN a, b, c`

Comment: Ok, the solution works for small datasets, but it requires a Cartesian product... I need to stop my request after hours, I have almost a billion nodes :-( Any other idea ?

Comment: @Vandy you can try splitting the query in two `MATCH`es, like:  `MATCH (x:X)
MATCH (a:A)-<something>-(b:B)-<something>-(c:C)
WHERE NOT EXISTS ((a)--(x)--(b), (x)--(c) )
RETURN a, b, c`.